# Linking Oracle and GitHub

Tags: git, oracle-sqldeveloper, version

I have some code in stored procedures inside packages in Oracle SQL Developer.
Is there any functionality built to link it to GitHub so the versions can be properly controlled? Any other idea on how to achieve this is welcome.

Comment: SQL developer is just a GUI, it just handles the communications between the user and the database(s). If you have a package stored then it will be in the Oracle database that SQL Developer is talking to. There is nothing to stop you from writing a SQL file containing the DDL statements for the packages then putting it into a Git repository (either locally or on Github) and you'll be able to open that file in SQL Developer and run it to rebuild the package.

Comment: So, should I create a couple of sql files (for package and package body) and save them as .sql files and then upload them to my repository every time I make a change? (Apologies about by lack of knowledge).

Comment: Check the `Team` menu in SQL Developer and the help for it.

Comment: Theres a git interface and you can export your db objects to files...

Comment: @thatjeffsmith how can I export a db package to a file?

Comment: right click on the package, save spec and body or or or https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/01/exporting-a-plsql-package-just-the-way-monty-likes-in-sql-developer/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thanks for your input. I've managed to save the package and body into a .sql file and uploaded to my repository. However, is there any way I could recreate my package with that file? (Kind of importing it).